# unsupported jvm version in netbeans 6.0

Tags: java, netbeans, jvm, failed-installation

I'm using win8 and trying to install netbean 6.0, i've been installed jdk 5 and 6 latest update but it say unsupported jvm. what i could do to make this application able to install?

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest JDK version (which would be JDK 8), instead of 7-year-old and 10-year-old versions?

Comment: same for netbeans: why v6.0 not the latest (8.0)?

Comment: i've been installed jdk 8 but it doesn't work. he keep preferred jdk 5 or 6. i tried to used --extract and java -jar it work but the process stop in jdk folder (?)

Answer (score 0):

JDK 6 and 6 are now unsupported by Oracle.  It's not recommended that you use these old versions now as there may be security vulnerabilities with them.

You really need to use Java 7 or 8 (preferably 8).  You should upgrade to NetBeans 8 as this fully supports these versions of Java.

Comment: i also done with java 7. thanks for your suggestion. but i install netbean 6 because these version provide SOA tools which is not available anymore in netbean latest version.